# SIGXFSZ runtime error

Tags: c, linux, runtime-error

I'm trying to submit the solution for [Spoj - Prime Intervals](https://spoj.com/problems/PRINT) problem. But I'm getting a runtime error [SIGXFSZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGXFSZ). It is given that, it occurs due to exceeded file size. I have used the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm to find the prime numbers. I don't understand what's wrong with my code and this is bugging me from last the 2 days. Please help me with the submission. Here is my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int t, turn;
    long i, l,u,k,j;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    /*Looping for t test cases*/
    for(turn=0; turn<t; turn++){
        scanf("%ld %ld", &l, &u);
        bool arr[u-l+1];

        /*Assigning whole array with true*/
        memset(arr, true, u-l+1);

        /*Sieve of Eratosthenes logic for assigning false to composite values*/
        for(i=0; i<=(int)sqrt(u)-l; i++){
            k=0;
            j = i+l;
            if(arr[i]==true){
                while((j*j + k*j) <= u){
                    arr[(j*j + k*j) - l] = false;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }

        /*Printing all the primes in the interval*/
        for(i=0; i<u-l; i++){
            if(arr[i]==true){
                printf("%ld\n", i+l);
            }
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

**Test Input:**

```
2  
2 10  
2 100
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
5
7
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Comment: What values you input to get runtime error?

Comment: @user1034749 The inputs are not given by me. It is a question from spoj, and the answer is not getting accepted by the online judge.

Comment: If you input `1` as first number, then why you need `2 100`? program handle only `2 10`.

Comment: Hm, you include output, then you get it, and only after that receive signal?

Comment: Try a test input using the range 50...100 instead of 2..100

Comment: regarding this line: `if(arr[i]==true)`   NEVER compare to `true` because `true` can be anything except 0/false.   two suggested methods: `if( arr[i] )`   or `if( false != arr[i] )`

Comment: the same comment about `true` also applies to the `memset()` statement, only there, I would suggest using `0x01` rather than `true`

Comment: what is the size limit being imposed by the spoj?  ON my computer (ubuntu linux 14.04, it runs with no signal being produced

Comment: what is expected to happen when `sqrt(u)` is less than or equal to `l`?

Comment: problems in the posted algorithm: 1) when the square root of the upper number is a less than the lower number, then the algorithm fails.   2) The upper number in the range is not processed. 3) for speed, the call to sqrt(u) needs to be extracted from the inner 'for()' loop, so it is only calculated once per value of 'i'  4) for speed, the calculation of i*i needs to be extracted from the inner 'while()' loop

Answer (score 1):

I ran the posted code. the results were far from correct.

Most of the numbers output are not primes and fails to check the last number is the range, as shown in the second set of results

Here are the results:

```
1      <-- 1 test case
20 100 <-- range 20...100
20     <-- the outputs
21 
22 
23
24
25
26
27 
28
29 
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

Note: using 1 as the low end of the range usually results with no output produced

here is another run

The output should have been 5 7 11

```
1     <-- test cases
5 11  <-- range
5     <-- outputs
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not try to minimize the size of the arr[] array, and if the upper end of the range is less than 16k then could declare the arr[] as `short` rather than `unsigned int`

The lowest valid value for the low end of the input is 2, but the code is not checking for that low limit, you might want to add that check.

The code makes no effort to minimize the number of loops executed by checking for the square root of the upper limit, you might want to add that check.

The code compiles cleanly, handles the case when the upper limit is a prime and when the lower limit is a prime as well as when the limit values are not primes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int numTestCases, testCase;
    size_t i; // index
    size_t lowLimit;
    size_t upperLimit;
    size_t k; // offset multiplier


    scanf("%d", &numTestCases);

    /*Looping for t test cases*/
    for(testCase=0; testCase<numTestCases; testCase++)
    {
        scanf("%lu %lu", (unsigned long*)&lowLimit, (unsigned long*)&upperLimit);
        unsigned arr[upperLimit+1];

        /*Assigning whole array to indicate entry is a prime*/
        memset(arr, 0x01, upperLimit+1);

        /*Sieve of Eratosthenes logic for assigning false to composite values*/
        //size_t sqrtUpperLimit = (size_t)ceil(sqrt(upperLimit));
        for(i=2; i<= upperLimit; i++)
        {

            if(arr[i])
            {
                if( i >= lowLimit )
                {
                    printf("%ld\n", i);
                }

                for( k=2; (i*k) <= upperLimit; k++)
                {
                    arr[(i*k)] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
} // end function; main
```

here is an edited version of the code, with the addition of some instrumentation in the way of prompts to the user via calls to `printf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int numTestCases, testCase;
    size_t i; // index
    size_t lowLimit;
    size_t upperLimit;
    size_t k; // offset multiplier

    printf("enter number of test cases\n");
    scanf("%d", &numTestCases);

    /*Looping for t test cases*/
    for(testCase=0; testCase<numTestCases; testCase++)
    {
        printf( "enter lower limit  upper limit limits\n");

        scanf("%lu %lu", (unsigned long*)&lowLimit, (unsigned long*)&upperLimit);
        unsigned arr[upperLimit+1];

        /*Assigning whole array to indicate entry is a prime*/
        memset(arr, 0x01, upperLimit+1);

        /*Sieve of Eratosthenes logic for assigning false to composite values*/
        //size_t sqrtUpperLimit = (size_t)ceil(sqrt(upperLimit));
        for(i=2; i<= upperLimit; i++)
        {

            if(arr[i])
            {
                if( i >= lowLimit )
                {
                    printf("%ld\n", i);
                }

                for( k=2; (i*k) <= upperLimit; k++)
                {
                    arr[(i*k)] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
} // end function; main
```

Using the above instrumented code and the input of:

```
5 2 3 30 31 20 27 2 3 4 5
```

it worked perfectly.

This was the output:

```
enter number of test cases
5
enter upper/lower limits
2 3
sizeof arr[]: 4
2
3
enter upper/lower limits
30 31
sizeof arr[]: 32
31
enter upper/lower limits
20 27
sizeof arr[]: 28
23
enter upper/lower limits
2 3
sizeof arr[]: 4
2
3
enter upper/lower limits
4 5
sizeof arr[]: 6
5
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out for the errors. I have fixed most of them. And your program doesn't work for the following input, `5 2 3 30 31 20 27 2 3 4 5`. It is not producing any output for the pair `20 27`. But strangely it works for `1 20 27`.

Comment: I just ran 1 2 3 and it worked correctly, outputting 2 3,  I just ran 1 30 31 and it worked correctly, outputting 31.  I just ran 1 20 27 and it worked correctly, outputting 23.  I just ran 1 4 5 and worked correctly, outputting 5.

Comment: Yeah it's working.. But I'm talking about the above said input with `5` test cases where one of the input is `20 27`

Comment: Adding the instrumentation may have shifted the stack somewhat, in which case the code probably contains some undefined behaviour.   My only guess is the changing of the size of the  arr[] array on the stack with each iteration may be a problem.   If that is the cause of any failure, then suggest preallocate a very large array on the file global space (outside of any function,  and just use the upper limit value during each iteration of the outer `for()` loop.